# Extract aggregation result from array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

The result of my aggregation is:

```
[{total: 405.3, qtde: 20, p1: 264.5, p2: 15, p3: 125.8, p4: 0, p5: 0, p6: 0, p7: 0, p8: 0}]
```

I want it to look like this (out of array):

```
{total: 405.3, qtde: 20, p1: 264.5, p2: 15, p3: 125.8, p4: 0, p5: 0, p6: 0, p7: 0, p8: 0}
```

Is possible?

Comment: How are you getting the result? Mongoos or mongo shell?

Comment: I using the mongoshell

Comment: @Bruno `aggregate()` method will always return an array of object.

Comment: In the `mongo` shell: `db.collection.aggregate([ { ...}]).toArray()[0]`. An aggregate result is a _cursor_, and there is a `toArray` cursor method.

Answer (score 0):

use this pipeline aggregate

```
'$addFields': {
                'exportFeild': {
                    '$arrayElemAt': [
                        '$ArrayField', 0
                    ]
                }
            }
```

Comment: I couldn't with your tip, but @prasad_'s tip worked.